# Display article element horizontally in HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I set the `article` element to display horizontally; inline, instead of vertically, one below the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## option 1

- set  `float:left`

```css
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  float: left;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<article>article 1</article>
<article>article 2</article>
<article>article 3</article>
```

## option 2

- set `display:inline-block`

```css
body {
  /*fix-inline-block*/
  font-size: 0
}
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  /*reset the font*/
  font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<article>article 1</article>
<article>article 2</article>
<article>article 3</article>
```

## option 3

- set `display:table/table-cell`

```css
section {
  display: table
}
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>article 1</article>
  <article>article 2</article>
  <article>article 3</article>
</section>
```

## option 4

- set `display:inline-flex`

```css
body {
  /*fix-inline-flex*/
  font-size: 0
}
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  /* reset the font */
  font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<article>article 1</article>
<article>article 2</article>
<article>article 3</article>
```

## option 5

- set `display:flex`

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}
article {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 16px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>article 1</article>
  <article>article 2</article>
  <article>article 3</article>
</section>
```

Comment: Which option would be considered "Best Practice"?

Comment: It really depends on which layout are you working on. They are all "best practice" per say.