# Expand elements to width of div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 27 hyperlink elements in a container div.  The hyperlinks are the alphabet letters like this:

A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | ALL

The div is the width of the page.  Right now, I have a class on the anchor tags that sets left and right padding to `3px`, so that I have spacing in between the pipes.  But the problem is the letters float to the left and I am left with a bunch of white space to the right of the letters.  How could I achieve spacing the letters (i.e. padding), so that letters expand to width of container div?  I am thinking the padding would be dynamic in such a way that it is set based on width of container div.

```
<style type="text/css">
.container { width:100%; }
.alphabetLinks { padding: 0px 3px; }
</style>

<html>
<div class="container">
<a class="alphabetLinks">A</a>
|
<a class="alphabetLinks">B</a>
|
</html>
```

UPDATE: solution must support IE9 and above.

Comment: If you can use flex-box, just add `display:flex;` to `.container`

Comment: Solution needs to work with IE9.  I think FlexBox is IE10+.

Comment: solution is display :table of course and pipe can be generated from a single pseudo or border eventually. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOYMWE example made for an answer that do not need to be posted below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1 - for modern browsers

- you can use `flexbox` for that

```css
.container {
  display: flex
}
a {
  flex: 1;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center
}
a::after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right:0
}
a:last-of-type::after {
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="alphabetLinks">A</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">B</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">C</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">D</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">E</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">F</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">G</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">H</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">I</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">J</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">K</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">L</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">M</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">N</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">O</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">P</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">Q</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">R</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">S</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">T</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">U</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">V</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">Y</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">Z</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">ALL</a>
</div>
```

## Option 2 -  fallback for older browsers

- you can use `css tables` for that

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width:100%
}
a {
  display:table-cell;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center
}
a:after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right:0
}
a:last-child:after {
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="alphabetLinks">A</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">B</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">C</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">D</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">E</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">F</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">G</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">H</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">I</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">J</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">K</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">L</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">M</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">N</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">O</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">P</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">Q</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">R</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">S</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">T</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">U</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">V</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">Y</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">Z</a>
  <a class="alphabetLinks">ALL</a>
</div>
```

Comment: just a few examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37574227/3448527, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35639285/3448527, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36852607/3448527

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [text-align-last](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last):

> The text-align-last CSS property describes how the last line of a
>   block or a line, right before a forced line break, is aligned.

I left only the class for the `div`. Code for the links became shorter.

```css
.alphabetLinks {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  width: 100%;
}
.alphabetLinks a {
  padding: 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabetLinks">
  <a href="#">A</a> |
  <a href="#">B</a> |
  <a href="#">C</a> |
  <a href="#">D</a> |
  <a href="#">E</a> |
  <a href="#">F</a> |
  <a href="#">G</a> |
  <a href="#">H</a> |
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="alphabetLinks">A</a>
    |
    <a class="alphabetLinks">B</a>
    |
    <a class="alphabetLinks">C</a>
    |
    <a class="alphabetLinks">D</a>
    |
    <a class="alphabetLinks">E</a>
    |
    <a class="alphabetLinks">F</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: table;  
    width: 100%;
}
.container .alphabetLinks {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9fyhmha/